# Path Hierarchy ElasticSearch and Folder Depth?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I am using path hierarchy tokenizer for a field in Logstash/ElasticSearch. So, if the path field is like /a/b/c, the tokenizer converts it to

```
    /a
    /a/b
    /a/b/c
```

I want to generate stats like

```
    a - 3 hits
    b - 2 hits
    c - 1 hit
```

What is the best possible way to do that? Also, I wonder if there is a way to add the folder depth in a separate field.

Answer (score 0):

For your custom purpose I think you can specify a custom pattern analyzer on the filed and take the terms aggregation of field. An **example** is as follows :

Define your custom analyzer :

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "nonword": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Create mapping :

```
 POST /test_index/_mapping/test_1
{
  "properties": {
    "dir": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "analyzed",
      "analyzer": "nonword",
      "fields": {
        "un_touched": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note : 'un_touched' field is kept for holding the original version of the data.

Populate data and perform the aggregation :

```
GET /test_index/test_1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "dir",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note** : This is only a minimal example and you should really care about the pattern;

Comment: Hi Shalin, 
Thank you so much! I have been trying but I could not get it working so far. I'll keep you posted.
Sorry,

Comment: Further googling suggests that Multi_Field had been removed from ElasticSearch sometime in 2014.

Comment: Oh sorry.. here is the fix for multi field: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/_multi_fields.html   I will update my answer; thanks;

Comment: @Ravi Sidhu answer is edited according to ES 2.X supporting format.

Comment: Thank you! I did make the change, but I am not sure how it varies from the initial path hierarchy tokenizer I used. In the example, if I have something like 

        /a
        /a/b
        /a/b/c
        /d
        /d/e
        /d/e/f 

How do I group these by the levels? Level1, and then drill down to level2 and so on?